# multiple languages in docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to build a docker container where I can have both python and java on it, as well as some other tools like: make. I have tried using docker images from the internet as the base image for my image, however I would like to build my own custom image to the different specification I have. I am particularly interested in providing the image with multiple languages and tools to which my program can use.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: How do you make a docker image with multiple languages and tools on it?

Comment: You _can_ install whatever you like in your container using the `RUN` command -  as described here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run.  Not sure this is a good idea though, as it mentioned in the Docker documentation "Each container should have only one concern"

Comment: hi @bunnmatt thanks for responding. I have a couple more questions. Currently, in order to get python and java for my docker container, I am using a image that can be found online here: https://hub.docker.com/r/rappdw/docker-java-python/~/dockerfile/. It uses run but also changes the ENV in the docker. Can you explain why this might be happening? Also if you don't think I should make my docker container too heavy by downloading multiple languages, what would be a recommended substitution?

Comment: Sorry can't really comment on that specific dockerfile I'm afraid but I have expanded on the comment above as an answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, has anyone come across a DockerHub repository that maintains a multi-language image?

Answer (score 3):

You can install whatever you like in your container using the `RUN` command - as described in the Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run

If you look at the [Dockerfile for an official Python image](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/1dcbfcceba5dc2d3ebf0a414926f2645aec0150e/3.7-rc/stretch/Dockerfile) you can see that this is how Python is installed.

To create a Docker image with your own choice of tools you could start from a base image such as [Debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/) or [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) and install the languages of your choice.

***However*** - I would not recommend this.  [As noted in the Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern) "each container should have only one concern", and the standard way of using Docker is to have one container run a single application using one language.

In your example you may have one Java-based container for one application, a separate Python-based on for your Python application and a third which contains build tools.

Comment: Hi @bunnmatt, if I wanted to run three containers for the single program, how could I do so. The program I have built runs on python but works with java programs. And it also needs different tools when running. How can I link each container to achieve this desired effect?'

Comment: @cruzhacker2020 I'm very new to Docker, but I found this, https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#decouple-applications. Seems like Docker would suggest running 3 different containers, ie one for each language. Just a guess... My instinct makes me think that multi-language containers seem fine??? Anyone feel free to post a follow-up on this!